# How to replace one character with multiple characters c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, character

I am doing some exapmples for my exam, and i find a problem replacing  string with other string. I know how to replace one character in string to others or revert a string.

We have a one string

```
 s="*****\n***\n****"
```

and we need to replace all "*" with "asd", and it should look like this

```
s="asdas\ndas\ndasd"
```

Comment: 1. Have a char array "repalcement" with teh content "asd". 2. Itterate over the string letter by letter. 3. If you hit a '*', write replacement[i]. 4. Increase i. If you are at the end of replacement, instead set i to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to write a for loop and check if the character is a `*` an keep track using a counter how many replacements have already been done.

Make use of the modulo `%` to see which character you need for the replacement and use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) to add the characters.

For example

```
string s="*****\n***\n****";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string subj = "asd";
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == '*') {
        sb.Append(subj[counter % subj.Length]);                        
        counter++;
        continue;
    }
    sb.Append(s[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Result

```
asdas
das
dasd
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/RLE9aF)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well. I am seeing this way for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like a Homework assignment and with those we avoid providing full code. It is way to important for you to do the coding yourself. But it comes down to

Itterate over the string until you run out of '*' characters:

1. Replace the first '*' with 'a'.
2. Replace the first '*' with 's'.
3. Replace teh first '*' with 'd'
4. Restart at 1

There is one important thing to note with strings: Strings are inmutable. You can not modify a string, only create one with a different value. Each replace will create a new, dead string in memory. For this scope it does not mater, but for anything larger it may. Consider changing a Char[] or StringBuilder rather then a raw string, the recreate a string.